# Image submit button works with Chrome but dosn't work with firefox?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, post, asp.net-mvc-4, custom-attributes

I have following HTML:

`<input type="image" src="/Images/actions/Delete.gif" alt="Delete" title="Delete" name="action" value="Delete"/>`

In my controller I have following custom attribute

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class MultiButtonAttribute : ActionNameSelectorAttribute
{
    public string MatchFormKey { get; set; }
    public string MatchFormValue { get; set; }
    public override bool IsValidName(ControllerContext controllerContext, string actionName, MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        return controllerContext.HttpContext.Request[MatchFormKey] != null &&
            controllerContext.HttpContext.Request[MatchFormKey] == MatchFormValue;
    }
}
```

And following action method should be called when delete is clicked

```
    [HttpPost]
    [MultiButton(MatchFormKey = "action", MatchFormValue = "Delete")]
    public ActionResult Delete(MessageModel model)
    {
        return Content("Delete clicked");
    }
```

This is perfectly working with Chrome but when submit button is clicked in Firefox my action method Delete() is not called.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Per HTML spec, `<input name="action" type="image">`, when clicked, sends form parameters named `action.x` and `action.y` but does NOT send one named `action`.  Firefox follows the spec, while Chrome does not.

Your server-side code seems to explicitly check for `action`, though, which is why it's not working in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers send the values in a different way. So instead of using the normal request you have to dig a bit deeper into the RouteData where you'll find all the values including the ones from Firefox. Here is a modified version of your custom attribute that works with Chrome, Firefox and IE.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class MultiButtonAttribute : ActionNameSelectorAttribute
{
    public string MatchFormKey { get; set; }  
    public string MatchFormValue { get; set; } 
    public override bool IsValidName(ControllerContext controllerContext, string actionName, MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        if (controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values[MatchFormKey] != null)
        {
            return (string)controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values[MatchFormKey] == MatchFormValue;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```